# python regex to match any valid english sentence

Tags: python, regex, text-manipulation

I was wondering if it is possible to write a python regex to match it up with any valid English sentence which can have alphanumeric characters and special characters.
Basically, I wanted to extract some specific elements from an XML file. These specific elements will have the following form:

```
<p o=<Any Number>> <Any English sentence> </p>
```

For example:

```
<p o ="1"> The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog </p>
```

or

```
<p o ="2">  And This is a number 12.90! </p>
```

We can easily write regex for

```
<p o=<Any Number>>
```

and `</p>` tags. But I am interested in extracting the sentences lying in between these tags by writing regex group.

Can anyone please suggest a Regex to be used for the problem above?

Also, if you can suggest a workaround approach, then it will be really helpful to me as well.

Comment: [Here is good explanation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/458723) why you should use something like BeautifulSoup or lxml to parse XML rather than regexp.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use an XML parser like [lxml](http://lxml.de/), regex is not suitable for this task.
Example:

```
import lxml.etree
// First we parse the xml
doc = lxml.etree.fromstring('<p o ="2">  And This is a number 12.90! </p>')
// Then we use xpath to extract the element we need
doc.xpath('/p/text()')
```

You can read more about XPATH at: [Xpath tutorial](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/default.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You should use an xml parser really. Example here http://www.travisglines.com/web-coding/python-xml-parser-tutorial.